# Please help me add to this script to get server hardware info

Tags: hardware, vbscript

(If this should be on stackoverflow just tell me...but it seemed more fitting here)

I found the script below online from this site:  http://forums.webhostautomation.com/showthread.php?t=8667

**Can someone please assist in adding (if possible) the following queries as well:**

****# of power supplies***

****Operating System and service pack level***

****# of NICs and what type of NIC (Gb/etc.)***

I'm not very good at scripting and once I started down the road of adding these features I ended up breaking the script.

Thank you in advance!

```
'*****************************************************
'       Script Witten by Larry Heintz
'       Jan 2005 www.larryheintz.com
' This script will connect to the computer name you
' enter and query and return the following information
'
' CPU:
'   - CPU Speed MHZ
'   - CPU Manufacture
'   - CPU Type
'   - CPU Current Load
'
' Memory
'   - Memory Bank
'   - Memory Stick Size MB
'   - Memory Speed MHZ
'   - Memory Type
'
' Hard Drive
'   - HD Model
'   - HD Size GB
'   - HD # of Partions
'   - HD Type
'   - Drive Letter
'   - Used Space
'   - Free Space
'   - Size of Partion
'   - Free Space %
'
' Script Usage:
' cscript hardware.vbs /computer:[Computer Name]
'*****************************************************
On Error Resume Next
' Dims stuff
Dim objStdOut, args
Dim servername
' Set Stuff
Set objStdOut = WScript.stdOut
Set args = WScript.Arguments.Named
servername = Trim(args.Item("computer"))

If WScript.arguments.count = 1 Then
    WScript.echo "CPU,Memory,Hard Drive Information for " & UCase(servername)
    WScript.echo ""
    If Not (errorChecking(servername)) Then
        '// CPU Info
        WScript.echo "CPU Information:"
        WScript.echo "================"
        For Each objCPU In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_Processor")
            Select Case objCPU.Family
                Case 2
                    cputype = "Unknown"
                Case 11
                    cputype = "Pentium brand"
                Case 12
                    cputype = "Pentium Pro"
                Case 13
                    cputype = "Pentium II"
                Case 14
                    cputype = "Pentium processor with MMX technology"
                Case 15
                    cputype = "Celeron "
                Case 16
                    cputype = "Pentium II Xeon"
                Case 17
                    cputype = "Pentium III"
                Case 28
                    cputype = "AMD Athlon Processor Family"
                Case 29
                    cputype = "AMD Duron Processor"
                Case 30
                    cputype = "AMD2900 Family"
                Case 31
                    cputype = "K6-2+"
                Case 130
                    cputype = "Itanium Processor"
                Case 176
                    cputype = "Pentium III Xeon"
                Case 177
                    cputype = "Pentium III Processor with Intel SpeedStep Technology"
                Case 178
                    cputype = "Pentium 4"
                Case 179
                    cputype = "Intel Xeon"
                Case 181
                    cputype = "Intel Xeon processor MP"
                Case 182
                    cputype = "AMD AthlonXP Family"
                Case 183
                    cputype = "AMD AthlonMP Family"
                Case 184
                    cputype = "Intel Itanium 2"
                Case 185
                    cputype = "AMD Opteron Family"
            End Select
            WScript.echo " CPU MHZ: " & objCPU.CurrentClockSpeed
            WScript.echo " CPU Manufacture: " & objCPU.Manufacturer
            WScript.echo " CPU Type: " & cputype
            WScript.echo " CPU Current Load: " & objCPU.LoadPercentage & "%"
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objCPU = Nothing

        '// Memory Info
        WScript.echo "Memory Information:"
        WScript.echo "==================="
        For Each objMem In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMemory")
            Select Case objMem.MemoryType
                Case 0
                    rtype = "Unknown"
                Case 1
                    rtype = "Other"
                Case 2
                    rtype = "DRAM"
                Case 3
                    rtype = "Synchronous DRAM"
                Case 4
                    rtype = "Cache DRAM"
                Case 5
                    rtype = "EDO"
                Case 6
                    rtype = "EDRAM"
                Case 7
                    rtype = "VRAM"
                Case 8
                    rtype = "SRAM"
                Case 9
                    rtype = "RAM"
                Case 10
                    rtype = "ROM"
                Case 11
                    rtype = "Flash"
                Case 12
                    rtype = "EEPROM"
                Case 13
                    rtype = "FEPROM"
                Case 14
                    rtype = "EPROM"
                Case 15
                    rtype = "CDRAM"
                Case 16
                    rtype = "3DRAM"
                Case 17
                    rtype = "SDRAM"
                Case 18
                    rtype = "SGRAM"
                Case 19
                    rtype = "RDRAM"
                Case 20
                    rtype = "DDR"
            End Select
            WScript.echo " Memory Bank: " & objMem.BankLabel
            WScript.echo " Memory Size: " & objMem.Capacity / 1024 / 1024 & " MB"
            WScript.echo " Memory Speed: " & objMem.Speed & " MHZ"
            WScript.echo " Memory Type: " & rtype
            WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objMem = Nothing

        '// Hard Drive Info
        WScript.echo "Hard Drive Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        For Each objHDInfo In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_DiskDrive")
            WScript.echo " Hard Drive Model: " & objHDInfo.Model
            WScript.echo " Hard Drive Size: " & CLng(objHDInfo.Size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) & " GB"
            WScript.echo " # of Partitions: " & objHDInfo.Partitions
            WScript.echo " Hard Drive Type: " & objHDInfo.InterfaceType
            WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objHDinfo = Nothing

        For Each objDisk In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = '3'")
            freespace = Left(objDisk.freespace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 4)
            totalspace = Left(objDisk.size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 4)
            usedspace = Left(totalspace / freespace, 4)
            freeperct = Left(100 / usedspace, 2)
            WScript.echo " Drive: " & objDisk.deviceid
            WScript.echo " Used Space: " & usedspace & " GB"
            WScript.echo " Free Space: " & freespace & " GB"
            WScript.echo " Total Space: " & totalspace & " GB"
            WScript.echo " Free: " & freeperct & "%"
            WScript.echo ""
        Next
        Set objDisk = Nothing
    End If
    WScript.echo "------------------------------------------------"
Else
    objStdOut.Write "Usage: cscript hardware.vbs /computer:[Computer Name]"
    objStdOut.close
    WScript.quit
End If

' Error Checking Function
Function errorChecking(ComputerName) 
    errorChecking = False 
    If err.number <> 0 Then 
        If err.number = "462" Then
            WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect"
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "70" Then   'General access denied error
            WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Permission Denied while trying to connect."
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "451" Then 'HEX Error is: 1C3
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147023174" Then   'The RPC server is unavailable.
            WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number -2147023174."
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147023836" Then
            WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number --2147023836."
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147022986" Then
            WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number -2147022986."
            err.Clear() 
            errorChecking = True
        Else
            WScript.echo "Error is: " & err.number
            WScript.echo "HEX Error is: " & Hex(err.number)
            WScript.echo "Desc. is: " & err.Description
            WScript.echo "Source is: " & err.Source
            err.Clear()
        End If 
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: This type of script is well in the realm of sysadmin duties.  Ok by me to leave it here.

Comment: There's a windows version of Cfg2Html (available from http://www.cfg2html.com/ ) that generates a ton of useful info. You'll have to join the yahoo group to grab it, and then you'll want the windows version of the script- the unix variations are pretty great, so they may include the info you're looking for here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a go at this.  New info is added at the bottom of the script.  One caveat, NIC (ndis) link speed is given by a different provider than the other NIC properties.  As such there are 2 new sections for NIC info: NIC Instance Information and NIC Link Information.  Each enumerates all the NICs in your machine and gives the relevant info.

```
'*****************************************************
'       Script Witten by Larry Heintz
'       Jan 2005 www.larryheintz.com
'       Modified Sep 2009 by Shawn Quillman for use on ServerFault.com
' This script will connect to the computer name you
' enter and query and return the following information
'
' CPU:
'   - CPU Speed MHZ
'   - CPU Manufacture
'   - CPU Type
'   - CPU Current Load
'
' Memory
'   - Memory Bank
'   - Memory Stick Size MB
'   - Memory Speed MHZ
'   - Memory Type
'
' Hard Drive
'   - HD Model
'   - HD Size GB
'   - HD # of Partions
'   - HD Type
'   - Drive Letter
'   - Used Space
'   - Free Space
'   - Size of Partion
'   - Free Space %
'
' Script Usage:
' cscript hardware.vbs /computer:[Computer Name]
'*****************************************************
On Error Resume Next
' Dims stuff
Dim objStdOut, args
Dim servername
' Set Stuff
Set objStdOut = WScript.stdOut
Set args = WScript.Arguments.Named
servername = Trim(args.Item("computer"))

If WScript.arguments.count = 1 Then
    WScript.echo "CPU,Memory,Hard Drive Information for " & UCase(servername)
    WScript.echo ""
    If Not (errorChecking(servername)) Then
        '// CPU Info
        WScript.echo "CPU Information:"
        WScript.echo "================"
        For Each objCPU In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_Processor")
                Select Case objCPU.Family
                        Case 2
                                cputype = "Unknown"
                        Case 11
                                cputype = "Pentium brand"
                        Case 12
                                cputype = "Pentium Pro"
                        Case 13
                                cputype = "Pentium II"
                        Case 14
                                cputype = "Pentium processor with MMX technology"
                        Case 15
                                cputype = "Celeron "
                        Case 16
                                cputype = "Pentium II Xeon"
                        Case 17
                                cputype = "Pentium III"
                        Case 28
                                cputype = "AMD Athlon Processor Family"
                        Case 29
                                cputype = "AMD Duron Processor"
                        Case 30
                                cputype = "AMD2900 Family"
                        Case 31
                                cputype = "K6-2+"
                        Case 130
                                cputype = "Itanium Processor"
                        Case 176
                                cputype = "Pentium III Xeon"
                        Case 177
                                cputype = "Pentium III Processor with Intel SpeedStep Technology"
                        Case 178
                                cputype = "Pentium 4"
                        Case 179
                                cputype = "Intel Xeon"
                        Case 181
                                cputype = "Intel Xeon processor MP"
                        Case 182
                                cputype = "AMD AthlonXP Family"
                        Case 183
                                cputype = "AMD AthlonMP Family"
                        Case 184
                                cputype = "Intel Itanium 2"
                        Case 185
                                cputype = "AMD Opteron? Family"
                End Select
                WScript.echo " CPU MHZ: " & objCPU.CurrentClockSpeed
                WScript.echo " CPU Manufacture: " & objCPU.Manufacturer
                WScript.echo " CPU Type: " & cputype
                WScript.echo " CPU Current Load: " & objCPU.LoadPercentage & "%"
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objCPU = Nothing

        '// Memory Info
        WScript.echo "Memory Information:"
        WScript.echo "==================="
        For Each objMem In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMemory")
                Select Case objMem.MemoryType
                        Case 0
                                rtype = "Unknown"
                        Case 1
                                rtype = "Other"
                        Case 2
                                rtype = "DRAM"
                        Case 3
                                rtype = "Synchronous DRAM"
                        Case 4
                                rtype = "Cache DRAM"
                        Case 5
                                rtype = "EDO"
                        Case 6
                                rtype = "EDRAM"
                        Case 7
                                rtype = "VRAM"
                        Case 8
                                rtype = "SRAM"
                        Case 9
                                rtype = "RAM"
                        Case 10
                                rtype = "ROM"
                        Case 11
                                rtype = "Flash"
                        Case 12
                                rtype = "EEPROM"
                        Case 13
                                rtype = "FEPROM"
                        Case 14
                                rtype = "EPROM"
                        Case 15
                                rtype = "CDRAM"
                        Case 16
                                rtype = "3DRAM"
                        Case 17
                                rtype = "SDRAM"
                        Case 18
                                rtype = "SGRAM"
                        Case 19
                                rtype = "RDRAM"
                        Case 20
                                rtype = "DDR"
                End Select
                WScript.echo " Memory Bank: " & objMem.BankLabel
                WScript.echo " Memory Size: " & objMem.Capacity / 1024 / 1024 & " MB"
                WScript.echo " Memory Speed: " & objMem.Speed & " MHZ"
                WScript.echo " Memory Type: " & rtype
                WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objMem = Nothing

        '// Hard Drive Info
        WScript.echo "Hard Drive Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        For Each objHDInfo In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_DiskDrive")
                WScript.echo " Hard Drive Model: " & objHDInfo.Model
                WScript.echo " Hard Drive Size: " & CLng(objHDInfo.Size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) & " GB"
                WScript.echo " # of Partitions: " & objHDInfo.Partitions
                WScript.echo " Hard Drive Type: " & objHDInfo.InterfaceType
                WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objHDinfo = Nothing

        For Each objDisk In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = '3'")
                freespace = Left(objDisk.freespace / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 4)
                totalspace = Left(objDisk.size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 4)
                usedspace = Left(totalspace / freespace, 4)
                freeperct = Left(100 / usedspace, 2)
                WScript.echo " Drive: " & objDisk.deviceid
                WScript.echo " Used Space: " & usedspace & " GB"
                WScript.echo " Free Space: " & freespace & " GB"
                WScript.echo " Total Space: " & totalspace & " GB"
                WScript.echo " Free: " & freeperct & "%"
                WScript.echo ""
        Next
        Set objDisk = Nothing

        '// Operating System and Service Pack
        WScript.echo "Operating System Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        For Each objOSInfo In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
                WScript.echo " Operating System: " & left(objOSInfo.Name,instr(objOSInfo.Name,"|")-1)
                WScript.echo " Service Pack Major Version: " & objOSInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion
                WScript.echo " Service Pack Minor Version: " & objOSInfo.ServicePackMinorVersion
                WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objOSinfo = Nothing

        '// NIC Info
        WScript.echo "NIC Instance Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        For Each objNICInfo In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
                WScript.echo " Caption (Name of NIC): " & objNICInfo.Caption
                WScript.echo "     MAC Address: " & objNICInfo.MACAddress
                WScript.echo "     IP Address(es): " & Join(objNICInfo.IPAddress,", ")
                set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & servername & "\root\WMI")
                set colNICProps = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSNdis_LinkSpeed")
                for each objProp in colNICProps
                        WScript.echo "     Active:" & objProp.Active
                        WScript.echo "     Link Speed:" & objProp.NdisLinkSpeed
                        WScript.echo "     Instance Name:" & objProp.InstanceName & " - " & objNICInfo.Caption
                next
                WScript.echo ""
        Next
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objNICinfo = Nothing

        '// NIC Info
        WScript.echo "NIC Link Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & servername & "\root\WMI")
        set colNICProps = objWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSNdis_LinkSpeed")
        for each objProp in colNICProps
                WScript.echo " Instance Name:" & objProp.InstanceName 
                WScript.echo "     Active:" & objProp.Active
                WScript.echo "     Link Speed:" & objProp.NdisLinkSpeed & " bps"
        next
        WScript.echo ""
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objNICinfo = Nothing

        '// Powersupply Info
        WScript.echo "Power Supply Information:"
        WScript.echo "======================="
        intPSCount = 0
        For Each objPSInfo In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\" & servername & "\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_PowerSupply")
                intPSCount = intPSCount + 1
        Next
        WScript.echo "     Number of Power Supplies: " & intPSCount
        WScript.echo ""
        WScript.echo ""
        Set objPSinfo = Nothing
    End If
    WScript.echo "------------------------------------------------"
Else
    objStdOut.Write "Usage: cscript hardware.vbs /computer:[Computer Name]"
    objStdOut.close
    WScript.quit
End If

' Error Checking Function
Function errorChecking(ComputerName) 
    errorChecking = False 
    If err.number <> 0 Then 
        If err.number = "462" Then
                WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect"
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "70" Then   'General access denied error
                WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Permission Denied while trying to connect."
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "451" Then 'HEX Error is: 1C3
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147023174" Then   'The RPC server is unavailable.
                WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number -2147023174."
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147023836" Then
                WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number --2147023836."
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        ElseIf err.number = "-2147022986" Then
                WScript.echo ComputerName & ",Error,Unable to connect error number -2147022986."
                err.Clear() 
                errorChecking = True
        Else
                WScript.echo "Error is: " & err.number
                WScript.echo "HEX Error is: " & Hex(err.number)
                WScript.echo "Desc. is: " & err.Description
                WScript.echo "Source is: " & err.Source
                err.Clear()
        End If 
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: I love you...in a man crush sort of way.  Thanks that worked beyond perfectly!

Comment: Whoah, let's not get carried away now :) (heh)

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation on retrieving information via WMI](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wmi_osjn.mspx)

Classes and Properties:

[OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx) (Win32_OperatingSystem)

- Name
- CSDVersion
- BuildNumber
- Version
- ServicePackMajorVersion
- ServicePackMinorVersion

[NIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(VS.85).aspx) (Win32_NetworkAdapter)

- Manufacturer
- ProductName
- MaxSpeed
- Speed
- AdapterType

[Power Supply (Current Sensor)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394113(VS.85).aspx) (Win32_CurrentProbe)

Examples:

- [Computer Hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587(VS.85).aspx)
- [Networking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595(VS.85).aspx)
- [Operating System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394596(VS.85).aspx)

A [repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/site/search?f[0].Type=Tag&f[0].Value=WMI) of WMI scripts

Comment: +1 - added the link for the repository for future reference

Comment: BTW - I got the number of power supplies from Win32_PowerSupply

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's Scriptomatic v2 Is one of my favorite tools.  I is like having the whole WMI API in my pocket. 

It will write the script you need for you:)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=09DFC342-648B-4119-B7EB-783B0F7D1178&displaylang=en

Comment: Gave you +1 cause I forgot about this program and it will help in the future

Comment: If you like the Scriptomatic2, there is now a PowerShell Scriptomatic.  It's the way I learned how to use PowerShell.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d87daf50-e487-4b0b-995c-f36a2855016e&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178) utility generates code snippets based on all WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) providers available on your system (which is what your existing script is using).  Incidentally, the language that the script above is written in is VBScript, so you will want to choose that as the language to use for code output by Scriptomatic.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

you could also try taking a look at sydi-server.  it's already made with some pretty nice features.  maybe at least looking at the script to see if it has something else you may want.

http://sydiproject.com/